# RVIZ through ssh

Tags: rviz, ssh, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know if there's a way to run rviz remotely.

I tried connecting to the PR2 and I'm just trying to use the rviz (just for some test, because i could actually use it from my computer connecting through the master).  I'm connecting with -X option: `ssh -X user@robot`

So, trying to use rviz, this is what I get:

```
rosrun rviz rviz # launching rviz

(process:27710): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message

(process:27710): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message

(process:27710): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
QGtkStyle was unable to detect the current GTK+ theme.
[ INFO] [1401799963.738721331]: rviz version 1.9.34
[ INFO] [1401799963.738810068]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
Segmentation fault
```

Any thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172665/rviz-through-ssh/) by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 649 on 2014-06-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-03**:
Just a wild guess: Is there even X running on the PR2?

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2014-06-03**:
I tried with xeyes (actually with tuxeyes) and it works pretty well the X server (as far as I can see)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rviz over SSH isn't supported.

See:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/44840/rosrun-rviz-and-x-window/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/50907/rviz-doesnt-start-when-run-remotely-throws-glxunsupportedprivaterequest-error/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/125861/running-rviz-through-x-forwarding-on-headless-machine/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2